# Getting "Could not find part of the path" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

im working on a project and what i try to do is to delete the 
files in my folder.

but I get the error:

`Could not find part of the path.`

The problem is that the path have a ' which does make part of the path. Here is my code:

```
foreach (var a in attachments)
{
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Files/'"+ a.FileName +"'"));

    foreach (string pathfile in files)
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(pathfile);
    }
}
```

the result path is this:

> 'c:.....\Files\'14d75c4e-c25f-4288-9a75-08a359fe6d844.png'"

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have 2 extra single quotes in your path, which you can see in your error message.  Just use `Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + a.FileName + ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved it.

the problem was the path and what i have done was little 
different what i had before.

i have create a method to return the root path.
And then i have add it a simple variable and execute the 
delete command.

**Here is my code:**

**Method:**

```
private string StorageRoot
   {
    get { return Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/")); }
   }
```

**Delete Command:**

```
 foreach (var a in attachments)
    {
      var myfilename = a.FileName;
      var filetoDelete = StorageRoot + myfilename;
      System.IO.File.Delete(filetoDelete);
    }
```

Hope this solution helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need single quotes.

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Files/"+ a.FileName));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your code has extra (un needed) single quotes.

```
....MapPath("~/Files/'"+ a.FileName +"'"));
```

Change this line;

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Files/'"+ a.FileName +"'"));
```

to

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Files/{0}", a.FileName));
```

Notice the change at the end of the code snippet(s).

Also, if I could suggest, wrap this in a `Try / Catch` (this would will help any future debugging as well).

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have try it, but now i get the error : the directory name is invalid?any ideia?

Comment: What is the path that is being returned?

Comment: im trying to find the url but i can´t see them.. 
i try to look in the console , have set breakpoints etc..
but can´t find...

Comment: Why not add a line for testing; `var x = a.FileName;` (firstly make sure that is correct and exisits) then find out what this is returning... `("~/Files/"+ a.FileName)` there is definatly something wrong with a path here.

Comment: the filename returns the correct name,

but the path return me null

Comment: Ok so then the problem is now, not about getting and deleting the files, its about getting the correct path returned. Try add some debugging and see why the path is getting returned as null.

Comment: Finally i have solved it.. take a look to my solution... and +1 for your answer and help